# Regex Matching even number of digits in a number with minimum length

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to form a regex that would work both the below mentioned examples:

Example 1. `202101310000-daily`
Example 2. `my_merchant_df_20210129`

The conditions are :

1. string contains even no. of digits (6 digits, 8 digits, 10 digits, so on).
2. String contains a minimum of 6 digits in a group.
3. the position of the digits grouping in a string doesn't matter.

I'm regex: `[0-9]+` is working for `202101310000-daily`, but I'm not able to create the regex that would satisfy both examples.

Basically for my use-case, there are groups of files that should have the date format of `yyyymd` or `yyyymmdd` or `yyyymmddHHMMSS`. I need to filter out those files which have that kind of format anywhere in the file name using
regex.

Comment: Regex just looks at patterns, it doesnt have math operations. #1 cant be done with regex alone. Are you using a language for this? `minimum of 6 digits in a group` might be `\d{6,}` unclear if a "group" is consecutive numbers or whole string

Comment: Are you just trying to extract/parse data-time sub-strings?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to extract file names that would contain a group of even no. digits but minimum 6 digits. Basically, there are group of files that should have the date format of yyyymd or yyyymmdd or yyyymmddHHMMSS. I need to filter out those files using java regex

Comment: Maybe split on the integers, feed it to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and then parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat 3 or more sets of 2 digits, and assert no digits to the left and right of the match using negative lookarounds.

```
(?<!\d)(?:\d\d){3,}(?!\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)` Assert no digit directly to the left
- `(?:\d\d){3,}` Repeat matching 2 digits 3 or more times to match 6 digits, 8 digits ect..
- `(?!\d)` Assert no digit directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X5mWLI/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<!\\d)(?:\\d\\d){3,}(?!\\d)";
```

---

To make it a bit more specific, you could either start by matching 19 or 20 for the year and repeat 2 or more times sets of 2 digits or you could use an alternation to match all the [exact patterns](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html).

```
 (?<!\d)(?:19|20)(?:\d{2}){2,}(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9YeHpg/1)

Comment: So, I tried this:

System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(?:\\d\\d){4,}", "my_records_df_20201212.txt")); //should return true but output is false

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my understanding of the way regex works?

Comment: @Siena `.matches` should match the full string. `System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^.*(?:\\d\\d){4,}\\b.*$", "my_records_df_20201212.txt"));`

Comment: I was banging my head. Thanks for pointing that out. :)
Pattern.compile(partitionRegex).matcher(fileName).find() worked like a charm